# Python same list gets altered by one function and not altered by another

Tags: python-2.7, variables, parameter-passing

I have read many SO pages about how the modification of mutable objects will be reflected outside the function, but immutable objects (obviously) won't. But I am a little baffled by this code where I send the same list to two different sort functions and one will modify it, and the other won't.

```
def bubbleSort(mylist):
    for i in range(len(mylist)):
            for j in range(i,len(mylist)):
                    if mylist[i] > mylist[j]:
                            mylist[i], mylist[j] = mylist[j], mylist[i]
    return mylist
```

The **bubbleSort()** above can be called like:

```
bubbleSort(mylist)
```

and it works just fine, with the midification of **mylist** being reflected in the caller. You can completely ignore the return value of **bubbleSort()** in the caller.

```
def mergeSort(mylist):
    listSize = len(mylist)
    shortSize = int(listSize/2)
    if listSize == 1:
            return (mylist)
    mylistLeft = mergeSort(mylist[:shortSize])
    mylistRight = mergeSort(mylist[shortSize:])
    i, j = 0, 0
    result = []
    while (i < len(mylistLeft) and j < len(mylistRight)):
            if mylistLeft[i] > mylistRight[j]:
                    result.append(mylistRight[j])
                    j += 1
            else:
                    result.append(mylistLeft[i])
                    i += 1
    result += mylistRight[j:]
    result += mylistLeft[i:]
    return result
```

The **mergeSort()** here cannot be called like the above call. Instead I have to call it like:

```
newlist = mergeSort(mylist)
```

and the **newlist** has what I want, while **mylist** has the unsorted list. So the **bubbleSort()** does not require a return statement whereas the **mergeSort()** is useless without it. I understand the need for return in recursion, but I was expecting not to have to use the return value in the calling function.

So my question is, what's the difference? Aren't the variables mutable in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mergeSort` function doesn't modify the list that's passed in at all. It creates a new list instead.

`results = []` creates a brand new empty list. Then you're appending elements to it. None of this modifies the original list that you passed in.

**EDIT**

By the way, it is indeed possible to perform a merge sort "in-place" (by modifying the original list instead of creating a new one), but it's a little tricky. As a general technique, you'd want to keep passing around the original list but with indexes to mark which portion of the list each recursive call is supposed to operate on.

Comment: Oh ok. So I tried *mylist = result* right before returning from the **mergoSort()**. But it still does not work.

Comment: That also doesn't modify the original list. It just changes what the variable mylist points to. E.g., try `def foo(x): x = 5` and then `a = 4; foo(a)`. That won't modify the value of `a`.

Comment: Ok, now I am curious, are you able to point me to a good tutorial for that? The more descriptive, the better.

Comment: @Deedaus Give http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/ a shot?

Comment: Your example does not work because a is mutable right? So foo works with a different object. But my list is not, as far as I understand. Please excuse my incessant questioning. I come from C++ or lower level background and this stuff is frying my brain. BTW I am loving the link already, thanks mate.

Comment: If you come from a C++ background, then think of `mergeSort` as taking a pointer to an array. `mylist = result` is just reassigning the `mylist` pointer to point to something else.

Comment: Oh ok. That clears up a lot. So I guess python functions will always take an address to an object, and assignments modify it only if it is mutable, while creates a new object and operates on that if it is immutable. Is that correct to say?

Comment: I'm not sure Python has a concept of an immutable object. I'm certainly not aware of anything in Python that will automatically create a new object when you try to mutate it.

Comment: Actually, I guess some objects are immutable in Python (e.g. strings), and operations there do tend to create new objects. So I think your understanding is correct.